# Delete rows from a cell given a specific condition

Tags: matlab, cell, conditional-statements

I have a cell type big-variable sorted out by FIRM (A(:,2)) and I want to erase all the rows in which the same firm doesn't appear **at least 3 times** in a row. In this example, A:

```
         FIRM 

 1997   'ABDR'  0,56    464 1641    19970224
 1997   'ABDR'  0,65    229 9208    19970424
 1997   'ABDR'  0,55    125 31867   19970218
 1997   'ABD'   0,06    435 8077    19970311
 1997   'ABD'   0,00    150 44994   19970804
1997    'ABFI'  2,07    154 46532   19971209
```

I would keep only A:

```
1997    'ABDR'  0,56    464 1641    19970224
1997    'ABDR'  0,65    229 9208    19970424
1997    'ABDR'  0,55    125 31867   19970218
```

Thanks a lot.

Notes:

I used `fopen` and `textscan`to import the csv file.
I performed some changes on some variables for all of them to fit in a cell-type variable

I converted some number-elements into stings

```
F_x=num2cell(Data{:,x});
```

I got new variable just with year

```
F_ya=max(0,fix(log10(F_y)+1)-4);
F_yb=fix(F_y./10.^F_ya);
F_yc = num2cell(F_yb);
```

Create new cell A w/ variables I need

```
A=[F_5C Data{:,1} Data{:,2} Data{:,3} Data{:,4} F_xa F_xb];
```

Meaning that within the cell I have some variables that are strings and others that are numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your names are stored in a `cell` array.  As such, your names would actually be:

```
names = {'ABDR', 'ABDR', 'ABDR', 'ABD', 'ABD', 'ABFI'};
```

We can then use `strcmpi`.  What this function does is that it **string compares** two strings together.  It returns `true` if the strings match and `false` otherwise.  This is also **case insensitive**, so `ABDR` would be the same as `abdr`.

You would call `strcmpi` like so:

```
v = strcmpi(str1, str2);
```

Alternatively `str2` can be a **cell array**.  How this would work is that it would take a single string `str1` and compare with **each string** in each cell of the cell array.  It would then return a logical vector that is the same size as `str2` which indicates whether we have a match at this particular location or not.

As such, we can go through each element of `names` and see how many matches we have overall with the entire `names` cell array.  We can then figure out which locations we need to select by checking to see if we have at least 3 matches or more per name in the `names` array.  In other words, we simply sum up the logical vector for each string within `names` and filter those that sum up to 3 or more.  We can use `cellfun` to help us perform this.  As such:

```
sums = cellfun(@(x) sum(strcmpi(x,names)), names);
```

Doing this thus gives:

```
sums =

 3     3     3     2     2     1
```

Now, we need those locations that have three or more.  As such:

```
locations = sums >= 3

locations =

 1     1     1     0     0     0
```

As such, these are the rows that you can use to filter out your matrix.  This is also a **logical** vector.  Assuming that `A` contains your data, you would simply do `A(locations,:)` to filter out all those rows that have occurrences of three or more times for a particular name.  I really don't know how you constructed `A`, so I'm assuming it's like a 2D matrix.  If you put in the code that you used to construct this matrix, I'll modify my post to get it working for you.  In any case, what's important is `locations`.  This tells you what **rows** you need to select to match your criteria.

Comment: Thank you very much, this code is really well explained which I appreciate a lot because I get to learn more. My 'names' are stored as`cell`arrays yes! I am applying it at the moment (I will let you know if it worked), but I will try and edit my question to see if seeing the code is a help! Thanks!

Comment: @user3557054 - OK, so it looks like your names are stored in `Data{:,2}`.  What I just wrote should still work.  `names` in this case would simply be `Data{:,2}`.  You would then take `locations` and subset your matrix `A` to select only those rows that we talked about.  Judging from how you constructed `A`, this should work

Comment: OK. I am trying it right now, I also think it will work. I will let you know at the end anyway! Thanks

Comment: @user3557054 - Ah so it worked I hope!... seeing as you accepted my answer :).  Awesome.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes it worked! I still wanted to verify again today but it's working! Thank you! :)